# How to deploy next.js project in production server through nginx?

Tags: nginx, next.js

I have the **next.js** project working properly in local.
Now,I want to deploy that project in the production server.I have tried following this link:

https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/static-html-export

But this is creating the index.html for each page given in the **next.config.js**. With that file how can I deploy the project in the **nginx**. Is there any way to generate a common **index.html** file so that i can point that file in the **nginx** .

Thanks in advance.